# Invalid JSON Escape Sequence in String

Tags: php, string, json

I am working with a MySQL db that has encoded polygon for google maps.  When I try to return the query as json, jsonlint complains..  I am not sure why its complaining , I did try escaping the "}" in the latlon but still get the same error.

```
Parse error on line 20:
...          "latlon": "}ciuF|a|pNcUr@d@es@
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

My json is:

```
{
    "maps": [
        {
            "group_id": "0",
            "user_id": "113",
            "group_name": "",
            "note": "",
            "field_id": "",
            "field_name": "West Pasture",
            "field_notes": "",
            "date_created": "12/31/2012",
            "acres": ""
        }
    ],
    "polygon": [
        {
            "polygon_id": "",
            "field_id": "1",
            "acres": "92",
            "latlon": "}ciuF|a|pNcUr@d@es@fIHXaNtCn@UxCjMlApAfFuBpI}E\ChJdEl@xAtE"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That error suggest there's a problem earlier in the json, not on that line..

Answer (score 16):

The problem is that there is a slash before the C which is not a valid escape sequence.

"}ciuF|a|pNcUr@d@es@fIHXaNtCn@UxCjMlApAfFuBpI}E`\C`hJdEl@xAtE"

```
JSON.parse('"\\C"');
```

This will give you a syntax error because it is trying to parse the string `\C`.  If you want a literal `\` in your property's value, you need to escape it.

```
"latlon": "}ciuF|a|pNcUr@d@es@fIHXaNtCn@UxCjMlApAfFuBpI}E\\ChJdEl@xAtE"
```

The relevant section from the [official grammar](http://json.org/):

```
string
    ""
    " chars "
chars
    char
    char chars
char
    any-Unicode-character-
        except-"-or-\-or-
        control-character
    \"
    \\
    \/
    \b
    \f
    \n
    \r
    \t
    \u four-hex-digits
```

Comment: Playing around this with myself, it took me 3 slashes to get it to decode in php. ie. `\\\C`

Comment: I figured it out by using: <pre>$tmp = str_replace('"', '\"', $maps['lat_lon']);
      $tmp = str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $tmp);</pre>  Are there any other special characters I need to be escaping that could be in a json string?

Comment: Are you concatenating your own string or are you using `json_encode`?